# a system with differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system which is described by the following differential equation. I want a closed form formulas to calculate $v_1(t)$ and $v_2(t)$ with the given parameters. In the following equations $p, k, c_0, c_2, R_1, R_2$ and $R_3$ are constants. Suppose initial values are $v_1 = V1$ and $v_2 = V2$ and $V1 > V2$.
$$I = \frac{-p}{v_1}$$
$$I_2 = \frac{v_1-v_2}{R_2}$$
$$I_3 = \frac{v_1}{R_3}$$
$$I_1 = I - I_2 - I_3$$
$$\frac{dv_1}{dt} = \frac{I_1}{(c_0+kv_1)} $$
$$\frac{dv_2}{dt}=\frac{I_2}{c_2}$$

Comment: What is $v$?  Cheers.

Comment: it's a typo and corrected

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you . . . ***plus one!*** on the question.